# LSTM Model - Validation Accuracy is not changing

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am working on classification problem, My input data is labels and output expected data is labels

```
Labels  Count
1      94481
0      65181
2      60448
```

I have made X, Y pairs by shifting the X and Y is changed to the categorical value

## create X/y pairs

```
df1 = df['Data_Used']
df1 = concat([df1, df1.shift(1)], axis=1)
df1.dropna(inplace=True)
```

```
    X   Y
    2   1.0
    1   2.0
    1   1.0
    2   1.0
    2   2.0
```

```
values = df1.values

encoder = LabelEncoder()
test_labels = to_categorical(encoder.fit_transform(values[:,1]),num_classes=3)
train_X,test_X,train_y,test_y= train_test_split(values[:,0], test_labels,test_size = 0.30,random_state = 42)

print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_X.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
```

(154076,)
(154076, 3)
(66033,)
(66033, 3)
Converting this to LSTM format

```
train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0],1,1)
test_X = test_X.reshape(test_X.shape[0],1,1)

# configure network
n_batch = 1
n_epoch = 10
n_neurons = 100
```

ModelArchitecture

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, train_X.shape[1],train_X.shape[2]), stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_X,train_y,validation_data=(test_X, test_y),epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1,shuffle= False)
```

Validation Accuracy is not Changing

```
Epoch 1/5
154076/154076 [==============================] - 356s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0844 - acc: 0.4269 - val_loss: 1.0814 - val_acc: 0.4310
Epoch 2/5
154076/154076 [==============================] - 354s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0853 - acc: 0.4256 - val_loss: 1.0813 - val_acc: 0.4310
Epoch 3/5
154076/154076 [==============================] - 355s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0861 - acc: 0.4246 - val_loss: 1.0814 - val_acc: 0.4310
Epoch 4/5
154076/154076 [==============================] - 356s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0874 - acc: 0.4228 - val_loss: 1.0825 - val_acc: 0.4310
Epoch 5/5
154076/154076 [==============================] - 353s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0887 - acc: 0.4208 - val_loss: 1.0828 - val_acc: 0.4310
```

What can be the changes to improve the model.

Comment: Can you share the part of the code to download/ load the `values`? Also does increasing `num_epochs` has any effect ?

Comment: @ankk I have updated the code, eventhough increasing the num_epochs my validation accuracy is not changing

Comment: can you share your data?

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason of this could be unbalanced data. You should have same amount of examples per label. And if you don't have that data, you can use **Loss Weights**. It is a parameter in **model.compile()**. You can learn more about Loss weights on google.

Also, I noticed you were using rmsprop as the optimizer. Try using Adam optimizer, as it is one of the best optimizer.

If, doing all of these I mentioned above, doesn't changes anything and the results are the same, remove the Dense() Layers and just keep 1 dense() layer, that is, just keep the last Dense Layer, and remove all the other Dense() Layers.

This will surely improve the model. But, if still it doesn't changes anything, then have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352037)